# How do I set the textarea to stretch across the page?

Tags: html, css

I need the textarea to stretch across the width of the web page. Here's what the developer tools Source in Chromes gives.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Musak</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Help">API</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">




<h2>Musak</h2>

<style type="text/css">
textarea {
 width: 800px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: black;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: green;
}
</style>

<div>
    <textarea cols="800" id="alltext"></textarea>
    <h2>Enter command</h2>
    <input type="text" id="command" size="800" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
    <p id="product" />
</div>


        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>


    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var uriDump = 'api/dump';
        var uriKey = 'api/key';
        var uriKey2 = 'api/key2';
        var uriDbase = 'api/dbase';

        function find() {
            var id = $('#command').val().toLowerCase();
            var res = id.split(" ");

            if (res.length > 0) {

                switch (res[0]) {
                    case "dump":
                        $.getJSON(uriDump + '/')
                            .done(function (data) {

                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + data);
                            })
                            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + err);
                            });
                        break;
                    case "dbase":
                        $.getJSON(uriDbase + '/')
                            .done(function (data) {

                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + data);
                            })
                            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + err);
                            });
                        break;
                    case "key":
                        $.getJSON(uriKey + '/' + res[1] + '/')
                            .done(function (data) {

                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + data);
                            })
                            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + err);
                            });
                        break;
                    case "key2":
                        $.getJSON(uriKey2 + '/' + res[1] + '/' + res[2] + '/')
                            .done(function (data) {

                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + data);
                            })
                            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                                var box = $("#alltext");
                                box.val(box.val() + err);
                            });
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }



        }
    </script>

</body>
```

**EDIT**

I found the piece of offending CSS..

In my site.css file:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: A width of 100% ought to work. `cols="800"` means 800 columns of text, or around 800ch of width, which is not what you want. By the way, it's better to move the <style> block up into the head, so you don't have errors in the HTML.

Comment: sadly... width=100% doesnt work. I have moved the style to the header and removed the width from the style and set it in the tag

Comment: Change this `textarea {width: 800px;}` to this: `textarea {width:100%}` (and, yes, remove the `cols` attribute.)

Comment: when I comment out '@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")'  in my layout.cshtml  file only THEN am I able to resize it to the appropriate with. Albeit manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the width to 100% using css.
By doing that the textarea will get stretched as per the width of your browser tab.

```
<textarea style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

or make the following changes

```
textarea{
width:100%
}
```

Comment: it is working with me. you should  remove cols attribute in textarea tag . write <textarea id="alltext"></textarea> instead of <textarea cols="800" id="alltext"></textarea>

Answer (score -1):

Make the following changes in your code:

1. Remove the `cols="800"` attribute from your textarea.
2. Set the value of width property to 100% in css.